# change multiple value of pandas column in a loop and update parent dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 'col2':['stuff' for i in range(7)]})
```

I want to subset the dataframe on `col1`, perform some stuff, and update the value of `col1`

```
for c in list(set(df.col1)):
    dd = df[df.col1 == c]
    #do stuff
    dd.col1 = [1,1,2,2]
```

I would then like to see these changes in `col1` observed in the parent dataframe, and increment the remaining values in `col1` accordingly. I would like this result:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,2,2,3,3,3], 'col2':['stuff' for i in range(7)]})
```

if the max value of `dd.col1` was 4, I would like the remaining values of col1 in the parent dataframe to increase to one greater: `4 + 1`, ie: `pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3,4,5,5,5]})`

I tried

```
df[df.index.isin(dd.index.to_list())]['col1']=dd.col1.to_list()
```

to update the values of `col1` in the loop unsuccessfully. Is there anything else I can do?

edit:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3], 'col2':['stuff' for i in range(9)]})
df
dg = pd.DataFrame()
uids = list(set(df.col1))
dd = df[df.col1==uids[0]].copy()
#do stuff
dd.col1 = [1,1,2,2]
dg=pd.concat([dg,dd], ignore_index=True)
#update values of parent data frame
dd = df[df.col1==uids[1]].copy()
dd.col1 = 1 + max(dg.col1)
dg=pd.concat([dg,dd], ignore_index=True)
dd = df[df.col1==uids[2]].copy()
dd.col1 = 1 + max(dg.col1)
dg=pd.concat([dg,dd], ignore_index=True)
```

here is code I use to show what I am aiming for:

- start with original `df`
- subset on first unique value of col1
- do stuff, and update values of `col1`. This stuff may or may not result in changing values of col1.
- bc values of col1 have been updated, I need to update the remaining values of col1 in the other unique values.
- after updating based on unique col1 value, I see the new df, `dg`.

Is there a tidier way to perform this?

Comment: You would typically not work with a manual loop. Also, in your example, [1,1,2,2] would not match the second group. Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: `for c in list(set(df.col1)): dd = df[df.col1 == c]` can be done in more _Pandas style_ and **faster** with `for c, dd in df.groupby('col1'):`. Your problem does sound like a `groupby` problem, you'll need to provide some more details as @mozway commented

Comment: updated original question, and shared further code